# New to coding,I can't figure out why my javascript buttons are not working properly?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

Here's the code:https://codepen.io/bryans98/pen/wvMeJzB

So each button is supposed to trigger a choice but for some reason, each button represents lapis every time! I can't find out how to fix it please help!

```js
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"]
player.currentChoice = choices[0];

function computerChooses() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
}

function compareChoices() {
  computerChooses();
  if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice) {
    displayResult("It's a tie! The computer and player both chose " + computer.currentChoice);
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  }
}

function displayResult(result) {
  const resultText = document.createElement('p');
  resultText.innerText = result;

  document.body.appendChild(resultText);
}

document.getElementById('lbutton').addEventListener('click', compareChoices, displayResult);

document.getElementById('pbutton').addEventListener('click', compareChoices, displayResult);

document.getElementById('sbutton').addEventListener('click', compareChoices, displayResult);
```

```css
#lbutton {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  position: static;
}

#pbutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: static;
}

#sbutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: static;
}

.c {
  padding: 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <h1> Welcome to the Ancient game of Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus!</h1>

  <div class="c">
    <button id="lbutton"><b>Lapis<b></button>
    <button id="pbutton"><b>Papyrus<b></button>
    <button id="sbutton"><b>Scalpellus<b></button>
  </div>

  <h2> The results are in...</h2>


</body>
```

Comment: const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"]
player.currentChoice = choices[0]; . Here is the issue

Comment: @VinaySomawat Can you explain to me on how to fix it please! I'm new to this and I'm finding a difficult time.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi So how would I go about fixing it, if you don't mind explaining it to me

Comment: you have to change the value of player.currentChoice based on the click of button

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other people said earlier **your issue lies under `player.currentChoice = choices[0];`** this line of your code where you always choosing the first index as a player choice. To fix this you should use [event interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and change the `player.currentChoice` based on selected elements, so you have to use it `compareChoices` function.

So your function should look like this:

```js
function compareChoices(e) {
  player.currentChoice = e.target.innerText;
  // rest of your function
}
```

Then your final code will work as expected:

```js
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"]


function computerChooses() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
}

function compareChoices(e) {
  player.currentChoice = e.target.innerText;
  computerChooses();
  if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice) {
    displayResult("It's a tie! The computer and player both chose " + computer.currentChoice);
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  }
}

function displayResult(result) {
  const resultText = document.createElement('p');
  resultText.innerText = result;

  document.body.appendChild(resultText);
}

document.getElementById('lbutton').addEventListener('click', compareChoices, displayResult);

document.getElementById('pbutton').addEventListener('click', compareChoices, displayResult);

document.getElementById('sbutton').addEventListener('click', compareChoices, displayResult);
```

```css
#lbutton {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  position: static;
}

#pbutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: static;
}

#sbutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: static;
}

.c {
  padding: 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <h1> Welcome to the Ancient game of Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus!</h1>

  <div class="c">
    <button id="lbutton"><b>Lapis</b></button>
    <button id="pbutton"><b>Papyrus</b></button>
    <button id="sbutton"><b>Scalpellus</b></button>
  </div>

  <h2> The results are in...</h2>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have

```
player.currentChoice = choices[0];
```

So player choice is always first - Lapis
If you change it to

```
player.currentChoice = choices[1];
```

choice will be Papyrus

try do something like this:

```
 <div class="c">
   <button id="lbutton" onclick="change(0)"><b>Lapis</b></button>
   <button id="pbutton" class="Papyrusbutton" onclick="change(1)"><b>Papyrus</b></button>
   <button id="sbutton" class="Scalpellusbutton" onclick="change(2)"><b>Scalpellus</b></button>
 </div>

function change(par) {
  player.currentChoice = choices[par];
}
```

Comment: ofc function change in js file